# CSS lining up icons issue

Tags: css, icons, font-face

I'm trying to line up some social icons (in @font-face format which why they only appear as letters) beside the Connect h3 in the yellow box but I'm stuggling. Any help would be great.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tobeeornot/qpdsZ/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey now used to **Display** `**inline-block**` as like this

```
    .footer-content p,  .social-media{
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: xxxxx;// top, middle, bottom --- as like requirement 
    }
```

Live demo http://jsfiddle.net/qpdsZ/1/

Comment: Thanks for that but how would I line up the Connect with the lif evenly upon a single line. Do they need to be the same font size or can I tweak it with css?

Comment: @tobeeornot Now you can used vertical-align as like this check demo http://jsfiddle.net/qpdsZ/4/

Comment: We seem to be getting there but this what it currently looks like on screen working locally. http://i1200.photobucket.com/albums/bb328/tobeeornot/bottom-container.gif

Comment: Hey i think you want to this check to demo http://jsfiddle.net/qpdsZ/6/    used sprite images and give to the background image in anchor tag.......

Comment: I see that. So you think I should jump the font and use sprite instead? Looks good but it still isn't lining up next to the connect. Thanks for your help BTW.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out, you have to adjust the font-size along with the `display:inline-block`. Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/meetsubhajit/qpdsZ/2/)

Comment: Thanks for that but I wanted to use a larger font for the social icons as they are very small at that size. Or should I just use images?

Comment: Please use images to fullfill that, you can use background image as well.